# oracle query not working in PHP 4

Tags: php, oracle11g

I am trying to execute an oracle(11g) query in PHP 4 which is finally failed. But the same query is successful in sql plus. Connection to database is ok coz all other queries are running successfully. I am pasting the query below :

```
SELECT to_CHAR(A.FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-RRRR HH:MIAM'),
       to_CHAR(A.TO_DATE,'DD-MM-RRRR HH:MIAM'), 
       A.PLACE_OF_VISIT, 
       A.PURPOSE_OF_VISIT, 
       C.EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
       A.CONTACT_NO,
       B.ABSENCE_TYPE,
       A.REMARKS,
       D.EMPLOYEE_NAME 
  FROM EMP_ABSENCE_DETAILS A,
       ABSENCE_TYPE B,
       EMPLOYEE_MASTER C,
       EMPLOYEE_MASTER D 
 WHERE A.EMP_CODE LIKE '%' 
   AND A.REASON_OF_ABSENCE = B.CODE 
   AND A.ENTRY_STATUS ='A' 
   AND ltrim(rtrim(C.EMPLOYEE_CODE))=ltrim(rtrim((A.OFFICER_EMP_CODE))) 
   AND ltrim(rtrim(D.EMPLOYEE_CODE))=ltrim(rtrim((A.EMP_CODE))) 
   AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR') >= to_date(FROM_DATE,'DD/MM/RRRR') 
   AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR')<= to_date(TO_DATE,'DD/MM/RRRR')
```

please help me

thanks and regards

Jessy

Comment: Do you get any errors returned? If so, it's useful to know what they were.

Comment: what is the php code that you are using? OCI8 extension?

Comment: no errors, its something related to date at the end of the query. when i removed the last date portion, its working in PHP. Somebody please tell me how to compare date in PL/SQL with php 4. thanks in advance

Comment: this is not a PHP related error... is a PL/SQL error, can you copy paste the error?

Comment: Are the FROM_DATE and TO_DATE columns dates or a varchar2s?

Comment: yep, FROM_DATE and TO_DATE are column names..

Comment: @jessica - I know they're column names, I'm asking what datatype they are!

Comment: i strongly believe that the error is something related with to_date() conversion.. coz when i removed those portion, the query is working fine...

Comment: @Mark Baker : they are of the type DATE

Comment: If they're already date, then don't cast them TO_DATE(): AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR')<= A.TO_DATE

Comment: in DB, FROM_DATE & TO_DATE are like DD/MM/YY:HH:MM AM i am taking only dd/mm/yyyy part

Comment: @jessica. If they're already dates, then casting to date will f*** up big time. They're stored as dates, not formatted date string, which is what you seem to be assuming. TRUNC(A.TO_DATE) will give you the date part (effectively setting the time part as 00:00:00.00 )

Comment: Off topic, but you do realise that PHP4 is end-of-life and no longer supported, right? That means no more security updates, so if a flaw is found you could get compromised. You should make plans to move to PHP5.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT to_CHAR(A.FROM_DATE,'DD-MM-RRRR HH:MIAM'),
       to_CHAR(A.TO_DATE,'DD-MM-RRRR HH:MIAM'), 
       A.PLACE_OF_VISIT, 
       A.PURPOSE_OF_VISIT, 
       C.EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
       A.CONTACT_NO,
       B.ABSENCE_TYPE,
       A.REMARKS,
       D.EMPLOYEE_NAME 
  FROM EMP_ABSENCE_DETAILS A,
       ABSENCE_TYPE B,
       EMPLOYEE_MASTER C,
       EMPLOYEE_MASTER D 
 WHERE A.EMP_CODE LIKE '%' 
   AND A.REASON_OF_ABSENCE = B.CODE 
   AND A.ENTRY_STATUS ='A' 
   AND ltrim(rtrim(C.EMPLOYEE_CODE))=ltrim(rtrim((A.OFFICER_EMP_CODE))) 
   AND ltrim(rtrim(D.EMPLOYEE_CODE))=ltrim(rtrim((A.EMP_CODE))) 
   AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR') >= trunc(A.FROM_DATE) 
   AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR')<= trunc(A.TO_DATE)
```

**EDIT**
for @powtac

```
AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR') >= to_date(FROM_DATE,'DD/MM/RRRR') 
AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR')<= to_date(TO_DATE,'DD/MM/RRRR')
```

has been replaced with

```
AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR') >= trunc(A.FROM_DATE) 
AND to_date('30/11/2010','DD/MM/RRRR')<= trunc(A.TO_DATE)
```